# How to convert a javascript animation to video on the server-side using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, animation, ffmpeg

I have a app where a user can create animations , I want to be able to convert these animations to video on server side, so user can save and share them eg YouTube, etc

Here is what I have so far , animation created using create js and ffmpegserver.js.

ffmpegserver.js.

This is a simple node server and library that sends canvas frames to the server and uses FFmpeg to compress the video. It can be used standalone or with CCapture.js

Test3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TweenJS: Simple Tween Demo</title>
<style>

canvas {
          border: 1px solid #08bf31;
          justify-content: center;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin: 0px auto;
          margin-bottom: 40px;
      }

      a {
        width: 150px;
        height: 45px;
        background: red;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 300px;
        color: white;
      }
      #container{
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
    #progress{
        margin: 30px;
    }
    #preview{
        margin: 40px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 45px;
        background: deepskyblue;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 300px;
    }


</style>

</head>
<body onload="init();">

<div>

<div id="container">
        <h1>Simple Tween Demo</h1>
    <canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
    <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://localhost:8081/ffmpegserver/CCapture.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8081/ffmpegserver/ffmpegserver.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.js"></script>
<script src="test3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test3.js

```
/* eslint-disable eol-last */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable quotes */
var canvas, stage;
    function init() {
        var framesPerSecond = 60;
        var numFrames = framesPerSecond * 5; // a 5 second 60fps video
        var frameNum = 0;

        var progressElem = document.getElementById("progress");
        var progressNode = document.createTextNode("");
        progressElem.appendChild(progressNode);

        function onProgress(progress) {
          progressNode.nodeValue = (progress * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
        }

        function showVideoLink(url, size) {
          size = size ? (" [size: " + (size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(1) + "meg]") : " [unknown size]";
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          a.href = url;
          var filename = url;
          var slashNdx = filename.lastIndexOf("/");
          if (slashNdx >= 0) {
            filename = filename.substr(slashNdx + 1);
          }
          a.download = filename;
          a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Download"));
          var container = document.getElementById("container").insertBefore(a, progressElem);

        }

        var capturer = new CCapture( {
          format: 'ffmpegserver',
          //workersPath: "3rdparty/",
          //format: 'gif',
          //verbose: true,
          framerate: framesPerSecond,
          onProgress: onProgress,
          //extension: ".mp4",
          //codec: "libx264",
        } );
        capturer.start();


        canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        var ball = new createjs.Shape();
        ball.graphics.setStrokeStyle(5, 'round', 'round');
        // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
        ball.graphics.beginStroke('#000000');
        ball.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
        ball.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1, 'round', 'round');
        ball.graphics.beginStroke('#000000');
        ball.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
        ball.graphics.lineTo(0, 50);
        ball.graphics.endStroke();
        ball.x = 200;
        ball.y = -50;
        createjs.Tween.get(ball, {loop: -1})
            .to({x: ball.x, y: canvas.height - 55, rotation: -360}, 1500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
            .wait(1000)
            .to({x: canvas.width - 55, rotation: 360}, 2500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
            .wait(1000)
            .to({scaleX: 2, scaleY: 2}, 2500, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
            .wait(1000)
        stage.addChild(ball);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            capturer.capture( canvas );

            ++frameNum;
            if (frameNum < numFrames) {
            progressNode.nodeValue = "rendered frame# " + frameNum + " of " + numFrames;
            } else if (frameNum === numFrames) {
            capturer.stop();
            capturer.save(showVideoLink);
            }
        }

        render();
}
```

Everything works fine, you can test it yourself if you want by cloning the repo.

Right now animation rendering happens in client side, I would like this animation rendering to happen in the backend side

What do I need to change to make this animation rendering in backend server side using Nodejs? any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to build an Rest Api with node.js and express ( or any kind of server api handeler)

. once you have got the outpot animation you will have to make an ajax post method request to the node.js server and let the server handle the CCapture.js ..

the main page in the serverwill look somthing like this .

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.post('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

check also NPM for more packages for node.js